# Parse string using pattern and Matcher

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching, matcher

I have string as

```
 str = "-------------Date 26032016
Hi Team, I am alone.
-------------Time 206066";
```

I need

**Hi team, I am alone.**

I am using following code but

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(-*?) H");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        while (m.find()) {
            part = m.group(1);
        }
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(.*?) -");
        Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(part);
        while (m1.find()) {
            part1 = m1.group(1);
        }
```

But not working.

I am trying to find any string between Date ( for eg.  -------------Date 26032016) and Time (for eg.  -------------Time 206066).

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: Hi there! Do you think you could expand a bit on what it is you a trying to do? If you're just trying to find that string could you not just match for the string itself? Or are you trying to find any string between the dashes and dates?

Comment: I need 

Hi team, I am alone.

Comment: @Kezz101 : yes I am trying to find any string between Date (-------------Date 26032016) and Time (-------------Time 206066)..

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using several matchers?
You could simply use:

```
-*Date \\d{8}\n(.*)\n-*Time \\d{6}
```

This assumes that the lines whown with your string value really are different lines and not just accidential line wrap.

Otherwise you would need to replace (or delete) the `\n` characters from the pattern

Comment: I am getting output as Hi Team, I am alone.--------- How to remove this "-----------"

Comment: Would assume `*` is missing from the second `-`. Or you do not have line breaks. Then `(.*)` is taking any character. You should the use `-+` for the second dash sequence. (at least one dash)

Comment: Ooops, may bad. You need to exlude the dash from the result:  `(.*[^-])`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sites like this to create a regex: https://regex101.com/

this should work:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-*Date \\d*\\r?\\n?(.*)\\r?\\n?-*Time \\d*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
            part = m.group(1); //part is now 'Hi Team, I am alone.'
```

}

Comment: I am getting output as
Hi Team, I am alone.---------
How to remove this "-----------"

Comment: please check you'r input string again, you can change (.*) to ([^-]*)